# Annotation to set a specific system property in Spring 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a set of unit tests. Some will use `dataSource`, others will want to use `hsqlbDataSource`. This datasource is not a wired bean into my unit tests/code, but is transitively used via templates and transaction managers. Therefore I intend to use bean defs like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDataSource"
    cache="true" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false"
    proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="hsqlbDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDataSource"
                 cache="true" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false"
                 proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean id="qmat-das-jdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate"
    c:dataSource-ref="${test.datasource:dataSource}" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="${test.datasource:dataSource}"/>
</bean>
```

I want for my unit tests (there are many of them, of course) to pick and choose which datasource to use. Ideally what makes sense to me is for each unit test to have an annotation which sets the system property to override the default datasouce with its own. Is there an elegant way to achieve that without property files, but just set the java property via an annotation?

Answer (score 0):

With an annotation it's not possible with out-of-the-box functionality, but have a look at [Spring 3 profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) as it allows to activate/deactivate groups of beans.

The beans can be activated with system properties or via code. This code could be put in a test superclass to activate the test-only beans:

```
springContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("test")
```